# Live Server is Working but button is not showing on vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, liveserver

Earlier Live Server Button (Go Live) was easily visible but now it is no longer visible.

PS: It works with <kbd>Cmd + L -> Cmd + O</kbd>, but the button is not visible.

What could be the possible reason behind this?

Following is the setting (JSON of it)

[image]

Comment: You can run the live server by right click.

Comment: or you can delete the live server or reInstall again maybe it's helpful for you

Comment: Right click on the status bar (the blue bar at the bottom) and make sure Live Server is selected.

Comment: Tried everything except the main answer and it worked. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right-click on the status bar at the bottom and make sure the Live Server (Extension) is selected. That will hide/unhide the `Go Live` button on the status bar.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Imagine being this dumb. Thanks anyway (Even writing this makes me feel embarrassed).

Comment: No worries, happens to best of us.

Answer (score 1):

You can also active your server by <kbd>alt + L + O</kbd>
keep in mind that you have to open with any folder either it have files or empty

Answer (score 1):

In the case when you only open the file, not the the folder, not only **Go Live** icon will not be appeared in status bar but also even **Live Server (Extension)** will not be listed by right clicking on status bar.
So **you have to open folder not just the file**.

Comment: i have opened a folder but it still doesnt show up.

Comment: @Luckie Is the folder you opened, the root folder of project?

Comment: im sorry but what do you mean with root folder or project, im not sure wich of it it is

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to live-server > config tab in extension settings.
2. Look for > Advance Custom Browser Cmd Line
3. Tap on Edit `settings.json`
4. On 4th line you may find it...
   `"liveServer.settings.showOnStatusbar": false`,
5. In my case it was false and I changed it to `true`
6. Restart VSCode and Enjoy...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

If Enabling the App in the taskbar, did **not** work for you:

**Are you being asked to update your VS Code extensions?**

Check the Cog icon in the bottom left of your window:

[image: The bottom left, where all software updates are handled]

If a blue notification symbol is present:

- **Click on the cog**
- Scroll to the bottom of the menu
- Select **Restart to Upgrade**

[image: the bottom of the menu]

Your app will reboot, and the **Go Live** option will repopulate.

Side note: I found this to be especially confusing, as it is possible to right click on your HTML file, **while Go Live is not present**, and Stop/Start your local server. This process has no visual affect, and the server does not load up.

Hope that this helps somebody out. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

@SomeEarth - Just to trump your dumbness I offer you, and any poor unfortunates who arrive here via google, this observation...

When the server is already active it displays `Port: 5500` not `Go Live`

I know. I'll show myself out!

Comment: haha, i guess it happens to everyone at some point (in any form of problem) .

Comment: This is not an answer and would have been better posted as a comment.

Comment: I disagree Michael. And honestly this pettiness is why people only use this site as a last resort these days.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VSCode-> Extention-> Install "Live Server" , Restart VS Code
Then Right Click on Status Bar and Enable "Liver Server(Extension)"
Done. You will see "Go Live"

Answer (score 0):

Just install/re-install the extension Live server from the settings -> extension. Then the button for Go Live will be available